# Conditional formatting with multiple parameters

Tags: formatting, expression, conditional-statements, ms-access-2013, logical-operators

I'm in Microsoft Access 2013 and trying to conditionally format a cell in a report. My first two expressions work well:

```
[House Party 2015]=Yes (Green)
[Declined]=Yes (Red)
```

I'm trying to add a yellow category where an item has been received `(House Party 2015 = Yes)` but not yet received `[House Party Donations List].[Received]=No)`

When I use an "And" expression `[House Party 2015]=Yes And [Received]=No`, nothing happens. I've tried reordering, creating a new field called "Not Received" `[House Party Donations List].[Not Received]=Yes`, but nothing seems to work.

Any guess as to why this is not working?

Answer (score 4):

Is this the sort of output you're looking for?

[image]

Here's the conditional formatting I applied (I think the key is to move your `AND` statement up to the top so it's checked first, otherwise it will look at your `[Donated]=Yes` rule, which will show as green):

[image]

**Edit:**
As per comments below, here's how to locate the Record Source property of your report (in Access 2013)..

Go in to Design View for the report and go to the Design tab, then click on the Property Sheet button:

[image]

The Property Sheet should open on the right-hand side. If you go to the "Data" tab of the Property Sheet, the first property listed will be the Record Source:

[image]

The Record Source property states where the report is getting its data from. The data can either be from 1 of your tables or saved queries, in which case it would say something simple like:

`[House Party Donations]`

Or, it can get its data from the result of an SQL expression, for example:

`SELECT Table1.[House Party 2015], Table2.Received FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID;`

If you want to do conditional formatting in your report using fields from different tables, it's best to get all your fields in to that Record Source first. This can be done by either referring to a saved query or write/build an SQL expression directly in to the report's Record Source.

If you update your original question to list the fields from the 2 tables and make it clear which field is common to both fields (i.e. how the tables can be linked through primary/foreign keys) then I can probably help you create the query/SQL for your report's Record Source.

For example, I mocked this up in the report's Record Source query builder:

[image]

I was then able to add the fields from different originating tables to the report:

[image]

And then I could reference them in conditional formatting without ! (bang) notation:

[image]

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Matt. That's what I would have assumed, too. My "yellow" expression is: **[House Party 2015]="Yes" And [House Party Donations]![Received]="No"**. Does it make a difference that the received field is coming from another table?

Comment: What's in the Record Source property of the report? I ask this because I don't think you'd need to reference the field from [House Party Donations] in that way (i.e. using the bang ! notation)... you should get the field in to the underlying SQL query in the report's Record Source and then you should be able to simply refer to it as `[Received]="No"` instead.

Comment: How do I find the Record Source property? I've tried using that notation, and it also does not work. I can't seem to get that field to be referenced in any way.

Comment: Have updated my answer. See below "Edit" for explanation of report Record Source property. As noted there, if you're unsure of how to build the query for the record source, please update your question to show the table and field names you need to use and how they could be related (i.e. which field(s) is common to each table).

Comment: Got it, Matt. My report's Record Source shows only the [Prospects] table. [Prospects].[ID]=[House Party Donations List].[Donor] and it's ultimately [House Party Donations List].[Received] that I'm trying to access.

Comment: Ok, so you need to create a query / sql expression that brings together all the fields you want to reference in your report. If you need help with the query, update your question and supply the structure of the tables you need to use (I.e list all the fields names for each table).